# Import variables from a ipython kernel to a python script

Tags: python, ipython

I would like to write a python script which can import all local variables from an existing ipython kernel.

I took a look at ipython API but did not really find what I want.

Here are several more precise questions :

1 - Is there a function from the ipython API to list all existing active ipython kernels ?

2 - Is it possible to fetch all variables from a kernel without launching an embed ipython ?

**EDIT :** The idea behind this is to make a variable explorer for python in text mode that could display local/global variables in a given kernel in real time

**EDIT :** I wrote the following class which do what I want. However, I think it is not optimal. In particular, `get_iopub_message` is very boring. Indeed, it gets all messages (even 'idle' and 'busy'), but I did not find a more direct method to access `who` output.

```
class Watcher(Thread):
    def __init__(self, km, delay):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.km = km
        self.delay = delay
        self.msg, self.variables = self.InitWhos()

    def run(self):
        ''' Main loop '''
        while True:
            try:
                data = self.km.get_iopub_msg(timeout=0.1)
                self.msg = 1
            except Empty:
                pass
            else:
                try:
                    if data['content']['execution_state'] == 'idle' and self.msg == 1:
                        self.msg, self.variables = self.Whos()
                except KeyError:
                    pass

            sleep(self.delay)

    def Whos(self):
        ''' Execute whos in the kernel and get output '''
        self.km.shell_channel.execute('whos', store_history=None)
        while self.msg == 1:
            try :
                data = self.km.get_iopub_msg(timeout=0.1)
                self.variables = data['content']['data']
            except KeyError:
                pass
            else:
                data = self.km.get_iopub_msg(timeout=0.1)
                self.msg = 0
        return self.msg, self.variables

    def InitWhos(self):
        ''' Init variables on startup '''
        self.msg = 1
        return self.Whos()
```

Comment: Can you save the variables of interest to file instead?  Using `cPickle`, for instance, and then load these in the script?

Comment: I edited my post. In fact I want my script to display the variables in real time

Comment: To find all kernels started by a notebook server, have a look at [this code](https://github.com/takluyver/nbmanager/blob/master/nbmanager/api.py). E.g. `for server in NbServer.findall(): print(server.sessions())`. Then in the kernel, you could set up something listening to the `post_run_cell` [event](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/callbacks.html) to send the variables to your process.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with 1, but 2 might be possible using the `inspect` module, see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html). I think you're going to struggle if you want to inspect a kernel from a separate process though...